# Error injecting the angularjs $location service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject the $location service in the following code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'kinvey', 'app.constants']);


            $injector.invoke(['$kinvey', 'CONST','URI_PATH', function($kinvey, CONST, URI_PATH) {
                $kinvey.init({
                    appKey    : CONST.appKey,
                    appSecret : CONST.appSecret
                }).then(function() {
                    console.log("success to connect");
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
                }, function() {
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
                });
            }]);

</script>
```

I am unable to inject the $location service in the above script. This script is in my index.html file which contains my `<ng-view></ng-view>` just to paint a better mental picture of the page structure.

Also I am getting the following error: [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/modulerr?p0=%24location&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3anomod%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/%24injector/nomod?p0=%2524location%0A%20%20%20%20at)

Answer (score 0):

Did yoy try to use the $locationProvider?, and then $locationProvider.$get().

$location service is not available before Angular bootstraps fully since only in the config phase of the app the services are instantiated using their corresponding providers.

Comment: Yes I tried using $locationProvider, however I am getting the error stated in the question. By the way what do you mean by fully bootstrap?

Comment: You can't get to the $location service until after angular initializes your application, you would have to do it after angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']); - you would need to inject it into a controller/directive/service   Could you provide a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to inject the $location service, so that if kinvey fail to initialize on startup then I relocate it to an error page.

Comment: You should use `location.href = http://www.yoursite.com/#!/errorView` for that purpose, it will cause a full page redirect, but it's only a radical case, or bootstrap Angular and then use the angular routing to redirect the use to the error view, the above solution will work on all common browsers